# pcre2 conditional replacement regex

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I'm trying to write some regex for inserting box drawing characters based on conditionals, but I keep getting the compilation error subpattern name expected.

Here is my code:

```
int match_pkg_details(char **pkgdetail, char *pkginfo)
{
    PCRE2_SPTR pattern = (PCRE2_SPTR)"^(?!Name|Architecture|URL|Licenses|"\
                    "Installed Size|Packager|Build Date|"\
                    "Install Date|Install Script|Validated By| *$).*$";
    *pkgdetail = malloc(4096); // FIXME malloc in initializer
    char *worker = *pkgdetail;
    size_t pattern_length = strlen((char *)pattern);
    int errornumber;
    PCRE2_SIZE erroroffset;
    pcre2_code *regex = pcre2_compile(
            pattern,
            pattern_length,
            PCRE2_MULTILINE,
            &errornumber,
            &erroroffset,
            NULL);
    if (regex == NULL)
    {
        PCRE2_UCHAR buffer[256];
        pcre2_get_error_message(errornumber, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("PCRE2 compilation failed at offset %d: %s\n", (int)erroroffset,
            buffer);
        return 1;
    }

    PCRE2_SPTR replacement = (PCRE2_SPTR)"(?(?=^Install Reason) a | ((?=(\\w) b | ((?=(\\s) c )))))";
                                                                                    // if starts with Install Reason replace with bottom line arrow }}}
    size_t replacement_length = strlen((char*)replacement);
    pcre2_code *replacement_regex = pcre2_compile(
            replacement,
            replacement_length,
            PCRE2_EXTENDED,
            &errornumber,
            &erroroffset,
            NULL);
    if (replacement_regex == NULL)
    {
        PCRE2_UCHAR buffer[256];
        pcre2_get_error_message(errornumber, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("PCRE2 compilation failed at offset %d: %s\n", (int)erroroffset,
               buffer);
        return 1;
    }
    pcre2_match_data *match_data =
            pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(regex, NULL);

    PCRE2_SPTR subject = (PCRE2_SPTR)pkginfo;
    size_t length = strlen((char *)subject);

    PCRE2_SIZE *ovector = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer(match_data);
    ovector[1] = 0;

    int rc;
    PCRE2_SIZE offset = 0;
    uint32_t options = PCRE2_NOTEMPTY_ATSTART | PCRE2_ANCHORED;
    while (offset < length - 1 && (rc =
         pcre2_match(regex, subject, length, offset, options, match_data, NULL)))
    {
        offset = ovector[1];
        options = 0;

        if (rc == PCRE2_ERROR_NOMATCH)
        {
            ovector[1] = offset + 1;
            continue;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rc; i++)
        {
            PCRE2_SIZE worker_len = strlen(worker);
            PCRE2_UCHAR output[4096];
            PCRE2_SIZE outlen;
            int rs = pcre2_substitute(
                    replacement_regex,
                    subject,
                    length,
                    offset,
                    PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_EXTENDED,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    (PCRE2_SPTR)"@",
                    1,
                    output,
                    &outlen);
            PCRE2_SPTR substring_start = subject + ovector[2*i];
            size_t substring_length = ovector[2*i+1] - ovector[2*i];
            snprintf(worker, 4096, "%.*s\n", (int)substring_length, (char*)substring_start);
            worker += (int)substring_length + 1;
        }
    }

    pcre2_match_data_free(match_data);
    pcre2_code_free(regex);
    return 0;
}
```

The string I'm matching against:

```
Name            : cinnamon 
Version         : 3.4.6-1 
Description     : Linux desktop which provides advanced innovative features and 
                  a traditional user experience 
Architecture    : x86_64 
URL             : https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon 
Licenses        : GPL2 
Groups          : None 
Provides        : None 
Depends On      : accountsservice  caribou  cinnamon-settings-daemon  
                  cinnamon-session cinnamon-translations  cjs  clutter-gtk 
                  gnome-backgrounds  gnome-themes-standard  gstreamer  
                  libgnome-keyring  libkeybinder3  librsvg  muffin  
                  python2-cairo  python-dbus  python2-dbus  python2-pillow  
                  python2-pam  python2-pexpect  python2-pyinotify  python2-lxml  
                  cinnamon-control-center  cinnamon-screensaver  cinnamon-menus                   
                  libgnomekbd  network-manager-applet  nemo  polkit-gnome  xapps  
                  python2-gobject 
Optional Deps   : blueberry: Bluetooth support [installed]
                  gnome-panel: fallback mode
                  metacity: fallback mode
                  system-config-printer: printer settings [installed] 
Required By     : cinnamon-sound-effects 
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None 
Replaces        : None 
Installed Size  : 8.31 MiB 
Packager        : Antonio Rojas <arojas@archlinux.org> 
Build Date      : Sat 09 Sep 2017 05:38:21 AM CDT 
Install Date    : Sat 09 Sep 2017 11:37:44 AM CDT 
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package 
Install Script  : No 
Validated By    : Signature
```

Currently, if I remove the replacement groups I get:

```
Version         : 3.4.6-1
Description     : Linux desktop which provides advanced innovative features
                    and a traditional user experience
Provides        : None
Depends On      : accountsservice  caribou  cinnamon-settings-daemon
                  cinnamon-session  cinnamon-translations  cjs  clutter-gtk  gnome-backgrounds
                  gnome-themes-standard  gstreamer  libgnome-keyring  libkeybinder3  librsvg
                  muffin  python2-cairo  python-dbus  python2-dbus  python2-pillow  python2-pam
                  python2-pexpect  python2-pyinotify  python2-lxml  cinnamon-control-center
                  cinnamon-screensaver  cinnamon-menus  libgnomekbd  network-manager-applet
                  nemo  polkit-gnome  xapps  python2-gobject
Optional Deps   : blueberry: Bluetooth support [installed]
Required By     : cinnamon-sound-effects
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
```

The intended output looks like:

```
├─ Version         : 3.4.6-1
├─ Description     : Linux desktop which provides advanced innovative features
│                    and a traditional user experience
├─ Provides        : None
├─ Depends On      : accountsservice  caribou  cinnamon-settings-daemon
│                    cinnamon-session  cinnamon-translations  cjs  clutter-gtk  gnome-backgrounds
│                    gnome-themes-standard  gstreamer  libgnome-keyring  libkeybinder3  librsvg
│                    muffin  python2-cairo  python-dbus  python2-dbus  python2-pillow  python2-pam
│                    python2-pexpect  python2-pyinotify  python2-lxml  cinnamon-control-center
│                    cinnamon-screensaver  cinnamon-menus  libgnomekbd  network-manager-applet
│                    nemo  polkit-gnome  xapps  python2-gobject
├─ Optional Deps   : blueberry: Bluetooth support [installed]
├─ Required By     : cinnamon-sound-effects
├─ Optional For    : None
├─ Conflicts With  : None
├─ Replaces        : None
└─ Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
```

a, b, and c are just there for testing purposes (I think I should replace them with named capture groups). I'll be breaking the `regex_compile` sections out to it's own method once I get the replacement working correctly. How can I replace named groups with `pcre2_substitute`?

Comment: What is `(?(^Install Reason)` supposed to be? I don't see it in any of the conditional operators at http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: I'm basing it off of the pcre2 documentation for if then else statements. http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC21

With `^Install Reason` I'm checking for that being the characters at the start of the line. If it's not there check for white space, and if there isn't white space match against letters. I'll then use `pcre2_substitute` to replace characters.

Comment: That page lists 5 kinds of conditions. Which type is this supposed to be, because it doesn't seem to match any of them?

Comment: Well, a lot of people confuse the term "conditional". Some just mean a regular "OR" to be conditional, or an optional substring. What text do you want to match? What good is fixing the current code if it won't help later? Look, most probably there are 2 types of typos in your current declaration: 1) remove unnecessary spaces - they are meaningful, 2) double the backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've tried it with double backslashes and without spaces, and I still get the same error subpattern name expected.  I can put the rest of the code in there, but most of it isn't related to this specific problem.

I have a match working that gets only the lines I want from the string, and from there I'm trying to add box drawing characters to the start of the lines.

@barmar It looks like it should match the first conditional `(?(condition)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`

Comment: You can't just put anything in `condition`, it needs to be either a capture reference or a lookaround expression (`DEFINE` and `VERSION` are special cases). Did you mean `(?(?=^Install Reason)...|...)` ?

Comment: @ZeroPhase See Lucas's comment. The main question is: What are you doing/trying to achieve? Please provide the pattern requirements.

Comment: I'll just toss the whole code sample in. I'm matching the subset, and trying to prepend box drawing characters based on the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to do your logic in the wrong place. You need to handle it in the substitution pattern, not in the regex pattern itself.

First, let's write a pattern which will identify the different parts of your string:

```
^(?:
    (?<remove>(?:
        Name|Architecture|URL|Licenses|
        Installed[ ]Size|Packager|Build[ ]Date|
        Install[ ]Date|Install[ ]Script|Validated[ ]By
    )\s*:[^\n]*\n)
    |(?<last>(?=Install[ ]Reason\s*:))
    |(?<field>(?=\S))
    |(?<cont>(?=\s))
)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BvoAgA/1)

That's with the `mx` options (`PCRE2_MULTILINE | PCRE2_EXTENDED`), but we won't really need `PCRE2_EXTENDED` in the C code.

This will identify some parts of the string and fill exactly one named capture group in the result:

- `remove` for parts to remove
- `last` for that last field
- `field` for other fields
- `cont` for value continuations (a line without a field label)

Next, we'll have to replace each of these parts with a different string:

- `remove` => *(empty string)*
- `last` => `└─` (I'll be using `\-` instead in the program below)
- `field` => `├─` (I'll be using `+-` instead in the program below)
- `cont` => `│` (I'll be using `|` instead in the program below)

We can let PCRE handle that through `PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_EXTENDED` ([docs](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC37)):

> The second effect of setting `PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_EXTENDED` is to add more flexibility to group substitution. The syntax is similar to that used by Bash:
>
> ```
> ${<n>:-<string>}
> ${<n>:+<string1>:<string2>}
> ```
>
> As before, `<n>` may be a group number or a name. The first form specifies a default value. If group `<n>` is set, its value is inserted; if not, `<string>` is expanded and the result inserted. The second form specifies strings that are expanded and inserted when group `<n>` is set or unset, respectively. The first form is just a convenient shorthand for
>
> ```
> ${<n>:+${<n>}:<string>}
> ```

So, using that syntax, our replacement string looks like this:

```
${remove:+:${last:+\\- :${field:++- :${cont:+|  :}}}}
```

---

Here's a full demo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8
#include <pcre2.h>

PCRE2_SPTR input =
    "Name            : cinnamon\n"
    "Version         : 3.4.6-1\n"
    "Description     : Linux desktop which provides advanced innovative features and\n"
    "                  a traditional user experience\n"
    "Architecture    : x86_64\n"
    "URL             : https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon\n"
    "Licenses        : GPL2\n"
    "Groups          : None\n"
    "Provides        : None\n"
    "Depends On      : accountsservice  caribou  cinnamon-settings-daemon\n"
    "                  cinnamon-session cinnamon-translations  cjs  clutter-gtk\n"
    "                  gnome-backgrounds  gnome-themes-standard  gstreamer \n"
    "                  libgnome-keyring  libkeybinder3  librsvg  muffin \n"
    "                  python2-cairo  python-dbus  python2-dbus  python2-pillow\n"
    "                  python2-pam  python2-pexpect  python2-pyinotify  python2-lxml\n"
    "                  cinnamon-control-center  cinnamon-screensaver  cinnamon-menus\n"
    "                  libgnomekbd  network-manager-applet  nemo  polkit-gnome  xapps\n"
    "                  python2-gobject\n"
    "Optional Deps   : blueberry: Bluetooth support [installed]\n"
    "                  gnome-panel: fallback mode\n"
    "                  metacity: fallback mode\n"
    "                  system-config-printer: printer settings [installed]\n"
    "Required By     : cinnamon-sound-effects\n"
    "Optional For    : None\n"
    "Conflicts With  : None\n"
    "Replaces        : None\n"
    "Installed Size  : 8.31 MiB\n"
    "Packager        : Antonio Rojas <arojas@archlinux.org>\n"
    "Build Date      : Sat 09 Sep 2017 05:38:21 AM CDT\n"
    "Install Date    : Sat 09 Sep 2017 11:37:44 AM CDT\n"
    "Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package\n"
    "Install Script  : No\n"
    "Validated By    : Signature\n";

PCRE2_SPTR pattern =
    "^(?:"
        "(?<remove>(?:"
            "Name|Architecture|URL|Licenses|"
            "Installed Size|Packager|Build Date|"
            "Install Date|Install Script|Validated By"
        ")\\s*:[^\n]*\n)"
        "|(?<last>(?=Install Reason\\s*:))"
        "|(?<field>(?=\\S))"
        "|(?<cont>(?=\\s))"
    ")";

PCRE2_SPTR replacement =
    "${remove:+:${last:+\\\\- :${field:++- :${cont:+|  :}}}}";

static void print_error(int code)
{
    PCRE2_UCHAR message[256];
    if (pcre2_get_error_message(code, &message, sizeof(message) / sizeof(PCRE2_UCHAR)))
        puts(message);
}

int main()
{
    pcre2_code *re;
    pcre2_match_context *match_context;
    int result, error;
    PCRE2_SIZE erroffset, outlength;
    PCRE2_UCHAR* outbuf;

    re = pcre2_compile(pattern, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, PCRE2_MULTILINE, &error, &erroffset, 0);
    if (!re)
    {
        print_error(error);
        return 1;
    }

    match_context = pcre2_match_context_create(0);

    outlength = 0;
    result = pcre2_substitute(
        re,
        input,
        PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,
        0,
        PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_GLOBAL | PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_OVERFLOW_LENGTH | PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_EXTENDED,
        0,
        match_context,
        replacement,
        PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,
        0,
        &outlength
    );

    if (result != PCRE2_ERROR_NOMEMORY)
    {
        print_error(result);
        return ;
    }

    outbuf = malloc(outlength * sizeof(PCRE2_UCHAR));

    result = pcre2_substitute(
        re,
        input,
        PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,
        0,
        PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_GLOBAL | PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_EXTENDED,
        0,
        match_context,
        replacement,
        PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,
        outbuf,
        &outlength
    );

    if (result < 0)
    {
        print_error(result);
        return;
    }

    puts(outbuf);

    free(outbuf);
    pcre2_match_context_free(match_context);
    pcre2_code_free(re);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
+- Version         : 3.4.6-1
+- Description     : Linux desktop which provides advanced innovative features and
|                    a traditional user experience
+- Groups          : None
+- Provides        : None
+- Depends On      : accountsservice  caribou  cinnamon-settings-daemon
|                    cinnamon-session cinnamon-translations  cjs  clutter-gtk
|                    gnome-backgrounds  gnome-themes-standard  gstreamer
|                    libgnome-keyring  libkeybinder3  librsvg  muffin
|                    python2-cairo  python-dbus  python2-dbus  python2-pillow
|                    python2-pam  python2-pexpect  python2-pyinotify  python2-lxml
|                    cinnamon-control-center  cinnamon-screensaver  cinnamon-menus
|                    libgnomekbd  network-manager-applet  nemo  polkit-gnome  xapps
|                    python2-gobject
+- Optional Deps   : blueberry: Bluetooth support [installed]
|                    gnome-panel: fallback mode
|                    metacity: fallback mode
|                    system-config-printer: printer settings [installed]
+- Required By     : cinnamon-sound-effects
+- Optional For    : None
+- Conflicts With  : None
+- Replaces        : None
\- Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
```

---

I think I should mention that in your case it would certainly be easier to just do the string manipulation by hand rather than going through a regex pattern.

Comment: Works perfectly only needed slight modifications for my program.

Comment: Tried it out, all it does is strip matched characters. It doesn't replace it with the replacement string.

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa I suggest you ask a new question with the details of your specific case.

Comment: Thanks @LucasTrzesniewski, I made it work already. I had to change a few things though

Comment: Hi @LucasTrzesniewski, the first pcre2_substitute now consistently returns PCRE2_ERROR_BADOPTION since the latest PCRE2 release. Any idea why this is happening??